# Is it possible to increase the TPS on a a paper server to make red stone computation faster?

Tags: minecraft

I normally run a paper server on my computer for single player and multiplayer but I'm wondering if its possible to increase the TPS to that things like repeaters have less delay.

Comment: Might be better over on “general computing” - or is there a “gaming stack”?

Comment: @user2864740 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/